# How can I print out a list of values from sql onto a page through python using Tkinter

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

Im trying to print out various values from my sql database onto a screen however im receiving the error that not all parameters are used. I think its due to the `BETWEEN %s AND %s` however i'm not sure.

```py
    def searchindividual():
        screen19 = Tk()
        screen19.geometry("300x250")
        screen19.title("Rooms")
        individualsiteID_info = sitename5_entry.get().strip()
        date1 = date1_entry.get()
        date2 = date2_entry.get()
        if individualsiteID_info:
            cursor = cnn.cursor()
            # combine the two SQL statements into one
            sql = ("SELECT * FROM Sites, questions "
                   "WHERE Sites.siteID = questions.siteID4_fk BETWEEN %s AND %s")
            cursor.execute(sql, (individualsiteID_info[0][0], date1, date2))
            answers = cursor.fetchall()
            # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
            for w in screen19.winfo_children():
                w.destroy()
            if rooms:
                for i, row in enumerate(values):
                    answeredquestions = row[0]
                    answeredquestionsvals = answeredquestions
                    btn = Button(screen19, text=answeredquestions)
                    btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
            else:
                Label(screen19, text="No recorded answers founf").grid()
```

Comment: You are trying to query multiple times in a single query. Don't do that, query separate.

Comment: Your SQL statement is not correct.  And you passed three arguments but the SQL statement expects two.

Comment: I separated the statements into two- one to select the siteID and another to select all values from the table given the date and siteID however its still giving the same error despite passing 3 arguments into the SQL statement which expects 3 values

Comment: Using single SQL statement is ok.  But your issue is the syntax of your SQL statement is wrong.  What is the column name for the two dates in your table?